# Database problem while integrating wordpress theme with magento

Tags: theme, ce-1.9.0.1, wordpress

I used df3dtheme database for magento installation and wptheme database for wordpress installation. Since I've 2 different databases, I'm facing a problem. Here is the screenshot.
[image: wptheme]

How to enter name, user name and password? There is no password for mysql.
P.S: I'm using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong here. First, you should have a password for root on your database, especially if you have PHPMyAdmin installed and you're going to tell everyone about it on the Internet. Second, you shouldn't use the root user in this situation, create another user with only the required permissions (and a password).